# How can I know which GPU my VGA output uses?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics, nvidia-optimus, external-monitor

I have an optimus GPU

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 640M] (rev ff)
```

and I use an external monitor. I have installed Bumblebee (and I use it to run certain sofware with `optirun`). I would like to know whether the external monitor (using a VGA cable) is using the Ivy Bridge or Nvidia GPU.

- How can I find that out?

Answer (score 1):

You could use lshw:

```
sudo lshw
```

The unused VGA output will probably show up as "UNCLAIMED".

Comment: I do get an `unclaimed` but it's `product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller`. Nice command, but I do not understand how it helps to discover whether I use the nvidia GPU.